# Getting the security origin of a URL

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

I'm writing a Chrome extension, and would like to be able to clean up given urls, so that I get their security origin. Using location.host seems to do the job, but it's not always usable - if I'd like to get the origin of an IFrame element, for instance, the call will be blocked.

Looking at [WebKit's source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/WebCore/platform/KURL.cpp), this seems like a far from trivial task. I can use either JavaScript, C++ or Chrome's API (using WebKit's code is an overkill, as it will drag another ton of files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out the guys from Chromium offer just that: [google-url](http://code.google.com/p/google-url/). As [described](http://code.google.com/p/google-url/wiki/Introduction) -

> *The Google URL Parsing and Canonicalization Library*
>
> This library is designed for Unix and Windows client and server programs that require URL parsing, canonicalization, or resolving.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Fast: hundreds of thousands of typical URLs can be parsed and canonicalized per second on a modern CPU.
> - Compatible: When possible, this library has strived for IE7 compatability. It supports Unix-style file URLs, as well as the more complex rules for Window file URLs.
> - Complete: This library is among the most complete implementations available.
> - Easily embededable: Unlike most implementations of URL parsing and canonicalization, this library is designed to be embedded into another application.

HTH someone in the future.